# Why does my header not take up the whole width of the page?

Tags: html, css

Sorry, if my problem is a little bit too specific, but I have not found the answer anywhere else. On my website, there is a header that is supposed to take up the whole width of the screen, but it does not. There is always a blank space between the top, and the sides. I have tried `display: block; min-width: 100%`, just `width: 100%` and many more variations but I just can't find out how to get rid of it. Anybody have ideas? Thanks!

**FULL CODE**

```css
/* GLOBAL */

body {
  /*background-color: #1abc9c;
 display: block;
 min-width: 100%;*/
}
#content {} header {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  border-top: 5px solid #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example Website</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">

    <header>

      <img src="REPLACE.png" />

    </header>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, the browser adds some margin to body element. Thus to fix it, add `margin:0;` to your body CSS.

```
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

[**JSfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/m4bv2agm/)

Comment: Wow, I cant believe it was that easy, but took me like three months to figure out. Thanks Steve!